# TDD in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tdd, code-kata

I'm about to participate in a Coding Kata and I would like to do it in JavaScript.

What tools and libraries do I need for TDD in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a JavaScript boilerplate project. A boilerplate project gives you all the tools you need to be instantly productive. Since you are looking to use Test Driven Development (TDD) you'll need a unit testing framework included. Here are some recommendations (*the ones I like towards the top*):

- [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) is a robust and opinionated set of tools, libraries, and a workflow that can help developers quickly build beautiful, compelling web apps.
- [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) - This is a great starting place if you want to build a single page app with Backbone.
- [Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/) - The most advanced responsive front-end framework in the world.
- Search google for "JavaScript boilerplate" to find your own perfect fit.

Answer (score 5):

I have had fantastic luck with [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and [Sinon JS](http://sinonjs.org/) frameworks. We use these tools now and even have them hooked into TFS to automate the test running when our server is being built. TFS kicks off Sinon and Jasmine. Take a look at them. Jasmine is more of a BDD framework and Sinon the unit testing. We also use QUnit on a couple projects.

Answer (score 1):

I recently began playing around with Jasmine and [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/). Although they're very easy to write (and to read too) they're a mess to work with. I also found [Test'em scripts](https://github.com/airportyh/testem), which is a small Node.js application that automatically tests your Jasmine/Mocha scripts.

Both of them are great, and paired with Testem, they make Javascript/Coffeescript/ very, very easy. Also, if you want to get started quickly, check nettuts screencast (No links left, sorry!) on Testem/Jasmine/Mocha. That's what got me interested on all of them in the first place.

Comment: Interesting. I never used Test'em scripts before. I might have to give this a shot myself.

I recently have looked into Google's Testacular (horrible name!) and I am impressed with what I see. It too is a Node.js based test runner.

Comment: It's very cool and it definitely makes it easier to test Javascript code. I don't know Testacular, though I agree that it has a horrible name. I'll check it out too.